# exporting gradle project as normal android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, git, gradle, build.gradle

I have downloaded an open source project from git hub and it was build using gradle. So while adding that android studio I added the grade, it downloaded the dependencies etc etc (was an hectic and time consuming task). Now the app is running fine on my Android Studio I want to pass this project to one of my colleague. Is there any option that my colleague dont have to go through all the hassle of downloading dependencies that gradle does `(using gradle.build).` Can I export it as `normal Android Studio project` and later on import it just using `Import Existing Android Studio project option` ?

Comment: but android studio uses gradle. either way, just copy the project directory.

Comment: @eriuzo If i copy the project directory, and want to use it in eclipse, it will work ?

Comment: afaik no. the project structure is different. you can try moving and/or renaming some folders to conform with old eclipse project structure, though it is not advisable because google only support android studio now.

Comment: @eriuzo and what about using the same project on a different PC with android studio ? Do I use the Import Existing project option or something else ? I want to just avoid the hassle of downloading the dependencies again

Comment: i think you need to copy the content of gradle cache folder. e.g. on my linux machine it's ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/

Comment: @eriuzo ok I will try with copying content of gradle too. this gradle thing seems to be a bummer if you cant just copy the project to another PC freely.

Comment: Is a problem if you have a bad connection, but the purpose of Gradle is exactly what you are trying to do, share your project and make that you and all your friends or team have the same configuration no matter your programming enviroment, OS etc..

Comment: @g2o but as the eriuzo said that we have to copy the caches/module/.... folder as well, who in this world care about going to cache folder and copying the modules while passing on the project , that make no sense at all to me :)

Comment: @Johnny well, gradle dependencies are typically only downloaded once, or when you update it, so no need to manually copy the cache folder.. but since you said you dont like downloading, well..

Comment: @eriuzo Eclipse has gradle support and can compile and run the project just fine.

Comment: @Johnny It doesn't make sense because you are trying to work around Gradle rather than with it. The whole point of the Gradle structure is so that your own project is very minimal. It contains only the files which belong to the project itself and downloads the libraries which it depends on.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice is the directory structure the same as in Android Studio?

Comment: @eriuzo If you want it to be, yes. The directory structure is entirely defined in the gradle build script. The default structure is defined by the Android plugin for gradle, but you can modify it from there.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand, it takes a while to download all your project dependencies, so one option that you should keep in mind if you want to avoid this kind of problems to your colleagues just save your project dependencies to a specific folder inside your project so your colleagues could easily resolved.

You can achieve that adding this line at the end of your `build.gradle`:

```
task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    into "$buildDir/output/lib"
    from configurations.runtime
}
build.dependsOn copyToLib
```

So when you finish solving your dependencies they will be at specific folder

For more info read this http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/how_can_i_gather_all_my_projects_dependencies_into_a_folder

Hope it helps!

Comment: since I am new to gradle, does the order matter where I add these lines, or I should add to the end ?

Comment: also $buildDir is a variable here or I should add absolute path here ?

Comment: I never tried different folder but should work with and absolute path

Comment: still since the build.gradle has old lines in it, it will still look for dependencies on Internet first ? right ..

Comment: This will copy your project downloaded dependencies to an specific folder, so when you finish you could share this dependencies to your colleagues... when they import your project to avoid donwload this dependencies they needs to add a local flatDir repository pointing to this folder to resolve everything locally